# first publish npm module does not download dependencies

Tags: node.js, package, npm

I just published my npm package. But now when I install it using `sudo npm install package-name -g`, it does download the package but does not download its dependencies. I know this because when I execute this package command `packagename path/to/folder` then shows an error about it dependencies that is `Error: Cannot find module 'hound'`. Hound is its dependency. Below is my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "package-name",
  "description": "description",
  "version": "0.1.1",
  "homepage": "url",
  "author": {
    "name": "Name",
    "email": "email@gmail.com"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "url to git"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "url/issues"
  },
  "licenses": [
    {
      "type": "MIT",
      "url": "url to LICENSE-MIT"
    }
  ],
  "main": "lib/package-name",
  "engines": {
    "node": "0.10.32"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "hound": "1.0.4",
    "async": "0.9.0",
    "replace": "0.3.0",
    "grunt": "~0.4.5",
    "node-dir": "0.1.6"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "preferGlobal": "true",
  "bin": {
    "cssimport" : "lib/package-name.js"
  }
}
```

**How can I change this so when user install my package then its dependency automatically downloads and starts working?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hound is set up as a devDepency, it's not going to be installed in a normal install.  If you change that to dependencies it will be.  If you need certain things as devDependencies to build your package (like grunt), leave them under that key.